# what diffrence is List.of(E e1, E e2, E e3) vs List.of(E... elements)

Tags: java, variadic-functions

List.of(E e1, E e2, E e3) return ImmutableCollections.ListN(e1, e2, e3);

```java
static <E> List<E> of(E e1, E e2, E e3) {
    return new ImmutableCollections.ListN<>(e1, e2, e3);
}
```

and List.of(E... elements) return ImmutableCollections.ListN(elements) too

```java
@SafeVarargs
@SuppressWarnings("varargs")
static <E> List<E> of(E... elements) {
    switch (elements.length) { // implicit null check of elements
        case 0:
            return ImmutableCollections.emptyList();
        case 1:
            return new ImmutableCollections.List12<>(elements[0]);
        case 2:
            return new ImmutableCollections.List12<>(elements[0], elements[1]);
        default:
            return new ImmutableCollections.ListN<>(elements);
    }
}
```

and ImmutableCollections.ListN<> Constructor

```java
@SafeVarargs
ListN(E... input) {
    // copy and check manually to avoid TOCTOU
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    E[] tmp = (E[])new Object[input.length]; // implicit nullcheck of input
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        tmp[i] = Objects.requireNonNull(input[i]);
    }
    elements = tmp;
}
```

I've previously noticed that List.of(E... elements) has worse performance because it uses variable arguments.
so overloaded versions such as List.of(E e1, E e2, E e3) have been created to not create an array internally.

However, it was confirmed that the overloaded version also creates an array internally while calling ListN, which receives variable arguments as parameters.

So, why was an overloaded version with a List size greater than 3 created?

Comment: It is a micro-optimization.  Presumably a result of some performance benchmarking that the OpenJDK team did.  If you really want to know the gory details, I suggest you get the JVM to show you the native code produced when these methods are JIT compiled.

Comment: Note also that the fact that `List.of(E e1, E e2, E e3)` creates an array is an implementation detail, which could change. The fact that `List.of(E... elements)` creates an array though, is not an implementation detail. These methods could certainly be implemented in a way such that the non-varargs versions do not create arrays. Whether this has better performance is another story.